Issue with adding form html and javascript code from Mautic to Optimizepress 3
After adding the Mautic form html code and javascript code (in WP page header), the submit button on the Optimizepress site does not work. On entering the name, email and pressing the submit button on the live OP3 page shows the spinning icon over the form submit button. However, the email and name are not sent to Mautic. After several minutes, one gets the message "Opt-in form not completed"
Any ideas on how to make this work on OP3 Smart theme and Wordpress?
Mautic version: 4.3.1
Optimizepress Builder version: 1.1.75
Optimizepress Dashboard version: 1.1.1
Wordpress version: 6.5.3
